# MATLAB equivalent of NumPy masked arrays?

Tags: matlab

### Desired behavior

In Python, I can created a masked array in NumPy like so:

```py
>>> import numpy as np
>>> x = np.arange(1, 7).reshape(3, 2)
>>> x = np.ma.array(x, mask=[[0, 0], [1, 0], [0, 0]])
>>> x
masked_array(
  data=[[1, 2],
        [--, 4],
        [5, 6]],
  mask=[[False, False],
        [ True, False],
        [False, False]],
  fill_value=999999)
```

And then computations treat it as if the masked values do not exist. For example, compare

```py
# Matrix multiplication on raw data.

>>> np.dot(x.data, x.data.T)
array([[ 5, 11, 17],
       [11, 25, 39],
       [17, 39, 61]])

# Matrix multiplication on masked data.

>>> np.ma.dot(x, x.T)
masked_array(
  data=[[5, 8, 17],
        [8, 16, 24],
        [17, 24, 61]],
  mask=[[False, False, False],
        [False, False, False],
        [False, False, False]],
  fill_value=999999)
```

Note that this is different from filling the masked values with zero or nan because things like division by zero are ignored. For example:

```py
>>> y = np.copy(x.data)
>>> y
array([[1, 2],
       [3, 4],
       [5, 6]])

>>> y / x
masked_array(
  data=[[1.0, 1.0],
        [--, 1.0],
        [1.0, 1.0]],
  mask=[[False, False],
        [ True, False],
        [False, False]],
  fill_value=999999)

>>> z = np.copy(x.data)
>>> z[1, 0] = 0
>>> z
array([[1, 2],
       [0, 4],
       [5, 6]])

>>> y / z
...RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in true_divide...
array([[ 1.,  1.],
       [inf,  1.],
       [ 1.,  1.]])
```

### Question

My question is: is there a way to replicate this functionality in MATLAB? I've tried `nan` but I get errors in downstream callee functions, e.g. [minFunc](https://www.cs.ubc.ca/~schmidtm/Software/minFunc.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can use *logicals* to do this. Create a matrix of logicals of the same size as the matrix you want to check and use it for indexing.
If you want to stick with `NaN`, you can either use `isnan()` to create a logical matrix of the same size and do as above. Or some fundamental functions have an option to set a `'omitNaN'`-flag, eg. `mean`.

```
A = rand(5,3);
% create logical matrix
lg = A > 0.5;
% index matrix
A(lg) = NaN % still a 5x3 matrix
A(~lg) % this is (most likely) a vector now! because MATLAB does not know how to handle rows with different number of elements
mean(A)
mean(A,'omitNaN')
mean(A(~lg))
```

---

**Output:**

```
>> A(lg) = NaN
 A =

       NaN    0.0975    0.1576
       NaN    0.2785       NaN
    0.1270       NaN       NaN
       NaN       NaN    0.4854
       NaN       NaN       NaN

>>A(~lg)

ans =

    0.1270
    0.0975
    0.2785
    0.1576
    0.4854

>> mean(A)

ans =

   NaN   NaN   NaN

>> mean(A,'omitNaN')

ans =

    0.1270    0.1880    0.3215

>> mean(A(~lg))

ans =

    0.2292
```

---

**Discussion:** Note that it is not clear how to arrange the remaining matrix elements if you cut out all elements of the logical index vector `lg` from the matrix `A`. Therefore, MATLAB collapses the matrix to a vector (interestingly it is a vector and not an array...). However, if you assign `NaN`s to the elements, you want to cut out, the shape is maintained. This ruins any function that uses all elements of a row/column if it cannot handle `NaN`s (eg. `max`is not affected). So `mean(A)` must fail -- unless you tell it to ignore `NaN` with `mean(A,'omitNaN')`. It then averages ever column (per default direction). Obviously, it is not the same result as the mean of all numeric elements, which are not `NaN`: `mean(A(~lg))`.

BTW it is the same result as if you would tell the mean to average all elements of a matrix which are not `NaN`: `mean(A,'all','omitNaN')` (note that the ordering of the flags is important here!)